# How do I use variables I set in Azure Pipeline UI as job name or displayName

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I set a variable like this

[image]

And this is how I see it after saving.

[image]

My variable does not have any special characters, spaces or periods. It's just a word and a number next to it. Like `Hello123`.

This is how I tried to use it this far and none worked!

1. `- job: $(myVariable)`
2. `- job: "$(myVariable)"`
3. `- job: '$(myVariable)'`
4. `- job: ${{ variables.myVariable }}`
5. `- job: "$($myVariable)"`

In displayName:
`displayName: "AAA $(OSName) BBB`

This will show as `AAA BBB`

What else can I try?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Job names are set at template compilation-time. You are defining runtime variables, which are available *after* compilation.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned, it's not possible because those are only defined after compilation.